# mod_proxy_fcgi missing [Centos6]

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy-fcgi

I comiled apache and php from source but now `mod_proxy_fcgi` missing here:

`/usr/local/apache2/modules/` any solution for this?

Comment: Did you enable that module when you [configured the source tree](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/install.html#configure) e.g. with `--enable-proxy-fcgi` ?

Comment: For apache compilation?